# @font-face font replacement to work crossbrowser

Tags: css

I'm having trouble getting this @font-face font replacement to work crossbrowser  can you please help. It works either in  all but ie 9 or works in all but ie 7 and ie 8.

I have the font as a .eot .otf .svg . ttf .woff?

Thanks

```
    /* works in all but ie 9 */
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Deutsch';
        src: url('/fonts/Deutsch.eot');
        src: local('/fonts/Deutsch'), 
             url('/fonts/Deutsch.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('/fonts/Deutsch.svg#font') format('svg'); 
    }
     /*from [http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-achieve-cross-browser-font-face-support/][1] */


    /* works in all but ie 7 and ie 8 */
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Deutsch';
        src: url('/fonts/Deutsch.ttf'),
             url('/fonts/Deutsch.eot'); /* IE9+ */
    }
    /*from [http://w3schools.com/css3/css3_fonts.asp][2]*/
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">



       /* code place holder location for css */



        #test
        {
            font-family:'Deutsch';
            font-weight:bold;
            text-decoration:underline;
            font-style:italic;
            font-size:30px;
        }

    </style>




</head>
<body>

    <div id="test">text goes here</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change your doctype........ Remove this line in your html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"

Comment: check this link.. http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/at-fontface

it shows compatibility of font face

Comment: thanks but its not cross browser - I just tested it

Comment: @font-face is supposed to work in all major browsers including older versions of IE (7 or 8). I think the problem might be declaring `styles` before even the DOCTYPE declaration. Put your `font-face` inside `style` tag in `head` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all rewrite your font-family like the following,

```
font-family: 'Deutsch', sans-serif;
```

If not by that you have to use a website for this, it will convert your ttf format to other different formats for font...

Check this, http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share this, as this appears to work.

```
    @font-face {
     font-family: 'Deutsch';
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: normal;
     src: url('/fonts/Deutsch.eot');
     src: url('/fonts/Deutsch.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/fonts/Deutsch.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/fonts/Deutsch.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/fonts/Deutsch.svg#Deutsch') format('svg');
    }
```

and Squirel out put this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'deutsch_gothicnormal';
    src: url('deutsch_-_copy.eot');
    src: url('deutsch_-_copy.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('deutsch_-_copy.woff') format('woff'),
         url('deutsch_-_copy.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('deutsch_-_copy.svg#deutsch_gothicnormal') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```